# jupyter notebookが開けない

Tags: linux, centos, jupyter-notebook

Windows から TeraTerm でCentOS のサーバに接続しています．
jupyter notebookを開きたいが、接続できないという状況です．

jupyterをインストールして jupyter_notebook_config.py も入れました．
`jupyter notebook -ip=*.*.*.* -port=8080` を実行すると `http://~~~` が出てくるので、Chromeにこれをペーストすると、応答に時間がかかりすぎてブラウザ上にエラーが表示されます．

ネットやポート番号などは確認して問題がなさそうなのですが、何か分かる方いましたら教えていただきたいです．

Comment: 「応答に時間がかかりすぎてブラウザ上でエラーが表示されます．」とはどのようなエラーですか？　またサーバー側のログに何か残っていませんか？

Comment: 「申し訳ございません。このページに到達できません」 というエラーです．ログは権限者でないと見れないようでした

Comment: CentOS 側でファイアウォールが動作していないか、動作している場合は外部からのアクセスを許可しているか確認してみてください。また、ポート番号に `8080` を指定していますが、他のアプリケーションで既に使用していないかも念のため確認してください。

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter Notebook (あるいは 今なら JupyterLab)をリモートのサーバーで起動するには
[Running a notebook server](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html) の記事があるので参考にできるでしょう

ここにその記事そのまま載せても巨大だし (コピー生成だけで)意味ないので, リンク程度で。
あと, 既知の問題点として Proxies など上がってます

**手順**

1. 記されている設定を行い, (直接) Jupyterを起動

   - 本当に起動できているか, ps コマンド(とか top とか) などで調べる
   - CentOS サーバー自体に Chrome Web ブラウザーが在るなら, 接続を試す
2. クライアントマシンで Chromeからの接続を試す
3. (最終的に)たぶん sshか何かで接続し Jupyter起動すると思われるが, それを試す
   (ssh 接続切った場合にも Jupyterが起動したままにできるよう, 手順が必要)